# Spring Boot @Retryable maxAttempts according to exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-retry

I wonder something about Spring Boot `@Retryable` annotation.

I want to implement `@Retryable` maxAttemps count according to Exception type, like:

```
if Exception type is ExceptionA:
@Retryable(value = ExceptionA.class, maxAttempts = 2)
if Exception type is ExceptionB:
@Retryable(value = ExceptionB.class, maxAttempts = 5)
```

Is it possible to do it with `@Retryable` annotation, or is there any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not directly; you would have to construct a custom interceptor (`RetryInterceptorBuilder`) bean and provide its bean name in `@Retryable.interceptor`.

Use an `ExceptionClassifierRetryPolicy` to use a different policy for each exception.

**EDIT**

Here's an example:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableRetry
public class So64029544Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So64029544Application.class, args);
    }


    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(Retryer retryer) {
        return args -> {
            retryer.toRetry("state");
            retryer.toRetry("arg");
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public Object retryInterceptor(Retryer retryer) throws Exception {
        ExceptionClassifierRetryPolicy policy = new ExceptionClassifierRetryPolicy();
        policy.setPolicyMap(Map.of(
                IllegalStateException.class, new SimpleRetryPolicy(2),
                IllegalArgumentException.class, new SimpleRetryPolicy(3)));
        Method recover = retryer.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("recover", Exception.class);
        return RetryInterceptorBuilder.stateless()
                .retryPolicy(policy)
                .backOffOptions(1_000, 1.5, 10_000)
                .recoverer(new RecoverAnnotationRecoveryHandler<>(retryer, recover))
                .build();
    }
}

@Component
class Retryer {

    @Retryable(interceptor = "retryInterceptor")
    public void toRetry(String in) {
        System.out.println(in);
        if ("state".equals(in)) {
            throw new IllegalStateException();
        }
        else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
    }

    @Recover
    public void recover(Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("Recovered from " + ex
                + ", retry count:" + RetrySynchronizationManager.getContext().getRetryCount());
    }

}
```

```
state
state
Recovered from java.lang.IllegalStateException, retry count:2
arg
arg
arg
Recovered from java.lang.IllegalArgumentException, retry count:3
```

Comment: can you share the example or docs for implementing the above approach ?

Comment: @Deadpool I added an example to the answer.